# Delete a line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In a Visual Studio, you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, whereas in Eclipse I am forced to select a line or, if it is empty, go the beginning of the line before clicking delete/backspace.

Is there a quick shortcut? Thanks!

Comment: for reference, ctrl-L deletes a line in Visual Studio, whereas ctrl-X xuts it. Usually they are interchangeable, but might have occasions when you have something on the clipboard and you want to delete not cut

Comment: while Ctrl+L in Visual Studio is cut the line, Ctrl+Shift+L means just delete the line.

Comment: If you want Visual Studio bindings in Eclipse you can go Ctrl+Shift+L,Ctrl+Shift+L to bring up Preferences > Keys. At the top of the window you will see a dropdown where you can set the Schemeto Visual Studio.

Comment: I like how the most simple questions are so useful!

Answer (score 257, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

From **Help**->**Key Assist**... there are all kinds of useful keyboard shortcuts for Eclipse.

For Mac users: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: This is the right answer, but it makes things hard to go between Eclipse and Resharper.

Comment: On the Mac this is ⌘ + D

Answer (score 122):

In the future, if you need to quickly find a keyboard shortcut for something simple, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+L on Mac ;)

Comment: Seems like that feature does not respect custom keyboard shortcuts. I re-defined [Ctrl] + [D] to toggle comment on current line, however, that help dialog still says *"Delete line"*.

Answer (score 54):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> should delete the line.

Answer (score 10):

You can reassign the `Delete Line` command to your favourite hotkey.
Window->Preferences
General->Keys.

Now type "Delete" and reassign the filtered command.

Answer (score 5):

if your are using MAC then it is

```
command + D  => ⌘ + D
```

Answer (score 3):

To quickly find shortcuts, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice), then type something approximating what your command does in the filter text for the key assignments. This works pretty well for most shortcuts, although it can be a bit tricky for some where the name of their menu assignment bears no relation to that of their command in this list (for instance, Team->Revert to base appears in the keys list as 'Replace with latest from repository'), so sometimes a little lateral thought is required :-) If no shortcut exists, it's easy to add one in the keys dialog.

Comment: Ctrl-L is the go to Line # shortcut, I presume you mean Ctrl-Shift-L

Answer (score 2):

And if you want it as a list to take a print or something, here is a link to the eclipse shortcut pdf.

[shortcut to pdf page](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 1):

press Ctrl+Shift+L TWICE and press TAB then you can type to find your shortkeys