# Eclipse copy/paste entire line keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, copy, keyboard-shortcuts, paste

Anyone know the keyboard shortcut to copy/paste a line into a new line in `Eclipse`, without having to highlight the entire line?

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd> turns my whole screen upside down (I'm on windows).  Interestingly, that's what's specified in the windows->preferences.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have this. IntelliJ does it very well. Ctrl-C will copy the whole line if nothing is highlighted. Also Ctrl-D duplicates a line as it is Ctrl-Alt-Down in eclipse.

Comment: Presumably flipping your screen upside down is not something you want to do often (unless you're a vampire/bat).  Get rid of your graphics config and accept the best answer.

Comment: @fastcodejava Many people praised IntelliJ, but they still use eclipse. Is it because eclipse is the requirement of a team?

Comment: Change Key preferences in Eclipse, assign some other shortcut "ctrl+alt+shit+down arrow" to "copy lines" action.

Answer (score 414, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>: copies current line or selected lines to below

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>:: copies current line or selected lines to above

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>: brings up a List of shortcut keys

See Windows/Preference->General->Keys.

Comment: That makes my whole screen upside down (I'm on windows).  Interestingly, that's specified in the windows/preference

Comment: If you are using Intel HD Graphics, it's quite possible that these shortcuts are binded by Intel graphics util. You can disable hotkeys from notification area util -> Graphic Options -> Hot Keys -> Disable. After that I could use those useful shortcuts.

Comment: put you may have to look at this http://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip

Comment: Anything for deleting a whole line?

Comment: try searching for it, you'd find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591172/delete-a-line-in-eclipse

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + L is bringing up "Quick Text Search" in STS

Comment: @Imray - Ctrl + D will delete the whole line.

Comment: In Ubuntu it does not work because CTRL+ALT+down and CTRL+ALT+up are already used (workspace switching). What you can do is to redefine  'copy lines' and 'duplicate lines' to other keys sequences. I have used CTRL+ALT+D for down and CTRL+ALT+U for up. It works perfectly.

Comment: I use Intel Graphic Card, when press `Ctrl+Alt+up/down`, have problem. My screen will rotate 180 degrees :) In this case, I must **disable default Intel Graphic Card shortcut keys** . It's my tip.

Comment: I have assigned new keys for these functions to be inline with vi editor `Windows>Preferences>General>Keys`

Comment: FWIW this does not appear to work when using a remote desktop either

Comment: @gopi1410 a better option is to simply ubuntu/unity "all settings / keyboard / shotcut / navigation" (at the list end) and remove (backspace) these keybings that I my case I never used and never will :). And also in CCSM http://askubuntu.com/a/70103/46437

Comment: Mac users: Analogously use "Alt-Command" instead of "Ctrl-Shift".

Comment: Had the problem that the shortcut was still not working after i disabled Intel HD Graphics-Hotkeys. The solution was to kill igfxHK.exe as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28650058/4870255

Answer (score 71):

(Tested on Windows) [Per below comments, works as well in Ubuntu, IBM RTC 4 / RSA 9]

1. In Eclipse, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> ***two
   times*** in succession (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> > type: Keys > <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. In 'type filter text' (search) text box, type `Copy Lines`
3. Select the filtered row, right click the 'Binding' field, and do `Select All`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. Give `OK`

From now on, for any line you want to duplicate, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: i added Ctrl+D for copy paste current line successfully. thanks

Comment: I didn't use `Ctrl + D` as it is already a registered shortcut for deleting a line in Eclipse.

Comment: Works on IBM RTC 4 / RSA 9.

Comment: I'm using eclipse mars on windows but not getting any row while filtering.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+V` is now the shortcut that lets you paste in MyClass:123 and jump to line 123, and linkifies stack traces. Probably too useful to overwrite now.

Comment: Doesn't look like a 'shortcut' to me.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu

Comment: I use Ctrl + P to paste current line to new line

Comment: @Nilesh Ctrl + P is a universal shortcut for "Print"

Answer (score 29):

You have to turn off the graphics hot keys that flip the screen. If you're on Windows, you need to right click on the Windows desktop and select "Graphics Properties..." (or something similar depending on your version of Windows). This will bring up a screen where you can manage graphics and display options, look for a place where you can disable hot keys, sometimes it's hidden under something like "Options and Support".  Turn off the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> hotkeys (alternatively you can just disable all graphics hot keys if you're not using them).

Comment: It works like charm. I am using Windows 7. To disable all I did is to Right click on the Windows desktop and select "Graphics Properties" ->Options. Then selected "Off" at the left side on the resulting screen. This disabled all hotkey combination. I think there is no way to disable only some them, its all or none. Anyway I didn't need them.

Comment: Yay! I didn't even had to restart Eclipse, just disabled the Intel HD Graphics shortcuts and ctrl-alt-down just started working.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to copy a line to the clipboard you can also use the trick:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>
followed by
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>

The drawback is that the file where you copy the line from becomes dirty.

Comment: What do you mean by dirty?

Comment: I mean by dirty that the file is marked as changed by Eclipse, while the content is not really changed.

Comment: To copy a line to the clipboard, Shift+ Down, followed by Ctrl-C, might be a better idea.

Comment: That requires you to move your right hand from the mouse to keyboard and back. The whole point of a 'copy line' feature is to prevent that.

Comment: Another solution (verified for eclipse latest version on Feb 2024) - Just don't select anything. Place cursor on the line and press ctrl+c, the whole line should be copied.

Answer (score 14):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> would delete a line
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> would undo deletion, with highlithing entire line
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd> cut or copy entire line

The advantage over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> suggested by other users is that it doesn't make eclipse think that the file was changed in any way. It's also faster and causes no problems even if the user has rotating screen issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd> keyboard shorcut. So there's no need to remap shorcuts for this.

Another way to go would be hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> until the entire line gets selected. If you've gone too far, of course you can select less with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Comment: One inconvenience is that it copies actually 2 lines, the original line plus line-break.

Comment: @user1278890 Sure, that might be considered both inconvenience or extra advantage :) Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 14):

If Your Window pc, you may try this, it's also for STS:

Ctrl + win + Alt + Down :: Copy current line or selected line to below

Ctrl + win + Alt + Up :: Copy current line or selected line to above

Answer (score 11):

I've written the [linecopypaste](https://github.com/larsch/eclipse-linecopypaste) plugin for Eclipse that mimics Visual Studio's copy/cut/paste behaviour. I've also found [copycutcurrentline](http://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/) which appears to do the same.

Answer (score 10):

On my Mac the default setting is is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

You can change/view all key bindings by going Eclipse -> Preferences (shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and then General -> Keys

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> Copies current line to below like notepad++ (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

If your whole screen is 180° rotted then you should disable your hotkey settings.

Right Click -> Graphics Options -> Hot Keys -> Disable

[image]

That it now you done try shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Try this in MAC.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>

it works.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone using Mac computer the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys doesn't work.

Try it with,

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>

It works.

Answer (score 4):

We can assign any command to any action(given) in Eclipse
From Menu Bar go to
**Window > Preferences**
then **search for the keys**
then **search copy line**
then click on copy line and then click on command in Binding
and peform a command which you wish to use for duplicating line i use **ctrl+shift+d**
you can choose whatever you want [image]

Answer (score 3):

I have to change the assigned key, 
e.g.

> Windows/Preference --> General --> Keys

Select "Duplicate Lines" under command
Click on "Binding"
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, I've tried the [linecopypaste](https://github.com/larsch/eclipse-linecopypaste) and it works great
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> -> Copy current (unselected) line, just like "yy" command in Vi/Vim
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> -> Paste it, like "p" command in Vi/Vim

Thank's Larsch for your work!

PD: Using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 in Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the hot keys for the Intel Driver worked for me for Windows 7. However, for Windows 8, when I tried that, it prevented eclipse from getting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> keystoke. I had to change the Intel driver key binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> (or something else it will accept). Eclipse then gets the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> and copies the line.

Comment: Maybe its not available in all versions, but looking at the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel there's also an option to "Disable" all shortcuts underneath the "Mange Hot Keys" section.  I just disabled it all...  (irritating that they force you to specify a key binding for everything when "Manage Hot Keys" is enabled)

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach:

```
1) Alt+Up and Alt+Down (or Alt+Down and Alt+Up, order does not matter)
2) Ctrl+C
```

But of course vim's "yy" is the fastest :)

Answer (score 2):

For mac, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down_arrow</kbd> works in netbeans' editor.

Answer (score 2):

It's working with me on , 
Eclipse  + Spring tool suite .

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 7. To disable that all I did is to Right click on the Windows desktop and select "Graphics Properties" ->Options. Then selected "Off" at the left side on the resulting screen. This disabled all hotkey combination. I think there is no way to disable only some them, its all or none. Anyway I didn't need them. So now crtl+Alt+Up and Crtl+Alt+down works for me in Eclipse and my screen stays same :) 
I think similar option also exist in other versions of Windows. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

To copy text from the begining of line to the cursor position: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>

It does the job and save a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> takes precedence over eclipse settings as hot keys. As an alternative, I try different approach.

```
Step 1: Triple click the line you want to copy & press `Ctrl`-`C`(This will
select & copy that entire line along with the `new line`).
Step 2: Put your cursor at the starting of the line where you want to to paste
your copied line & press `Ctrl`-`V`.(This will paste that entire line & will
push previous existing line to the new line, which we wanted in the first place).
```

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> flips my screen so I overrode that in the Eclipse shortcuts via 
Window => Preferences => General => Keys. 
Search for "dupl" to find the Duplicate Lines command.  I overrode the default and chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  For me, that's easy to remember just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to delete lines

Answer (score 0):

For personal usage, I add a vim plugin like [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) to Eclipse and just use `yy` to copy entire line.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> worked for me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcut way to do this is press Ctrl+Shift+L and select which command you want to perform and hit enter [image]

its best practice for beginner.

Answer (score 0):

See how to make the eclipse default shortcut work <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

1. **Select line:** Put cursor on the line to copy, select line with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> if cursor in the end of line or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> if cursor is in starting of line
2. **Duplicate line below (default expected behavior) or above** <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> but the key here is you need to select the line/block

Some answers focus on disabling the screen Rotation in Windows or any other OS, that applies to prevent accidental keypress.