# How to create a shortcut which copy line where cursor on

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse copy/paste entire line keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321938/eclipse-copy-paste-entire-line-keyboard-shortcut)

I want to create an eclipse shortcut.

Wherever line cursor on (without selection) when pressed Ctrl+C, eclipse will copy the whole line to clipboard.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you search before asking question? it was already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321938/eclipse-copy-paste-entire-line-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: @jFrenetic It's not the same question - copy to clipboard vs copy to new line.

Comment: @vanaprogeja Then the title should explicitly specify that. Moreover the second answer provided by `larsh` covers copying to clipboard as well.

Answer (score 1):

Key bindings can be associated with commands, but this operation would be 3 commands - Line Start, Select Line End, Copy. You'd have to [implement your own command](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) to execute all the three (id = org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.goto.lineStart, id = org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.select.lineEnd and id = org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy). But setting Ctrl+C as key binding would conflict with existing binding - Copy.