# How to copy a line to clipboard in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to switch to Eclipse from my other IDE and everything works fine so far except for the problem described in the title.

In my previous IDE (Idea) I would position a cursor on a line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and the whole line would go to clipboard (if nothing is selected).

Is there any way to copy the whole current line of code to a clipboard with a single shortcut in Eclipse? I.e. without pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> twice, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

PS JIC: I don't want to duplicate current line up or down - I know how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321938/eclipse-copy-paste-entire-line-keyboard-shortcut brings up https://github.com/larsch/eclipse-linecopypaste which should do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Try the Windows/Preference->Keys dialog, if you cant find what you are after, you can always define your own...

You could also try taking a look at this, which does exactly what you expect from ctrl+c without a selection
http://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/

Answer (score 6):

Do a triple mouse click to select the line, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for the copy operation.

Comment: Now I would really like to know the reasons for downvoting, as that answer is perfectly valid...

Comment: it is valid but he didn't ask that, he ask how to copy entire line to clipboard without selecting a line...similar to ctrl+d (erase current line) but for copy

Comment: I'm reading the question as "How to do it more easily than..." instead of "Avoid selection at all cost".

Comment: Personnaly, I use shortcuts in order to use mouse the less as possible, thus, triple clicking is not the way I searched for, tough it works. This is maybe the reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) to integrate the power of [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) into edting with Eclipse:

```
"+yy
```

copies current line into clipboard in Vim :)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> to increase the selection. After a couple of times the whole line will be selected and then you can copy it.