# Eclipse Duplicate line keyboard shortcut on MAC

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

This topic is related to [Eclipse copy/paste entire line keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321938/eclipse-copy-paste-entire-line-keyboard-shortcut/41154457)

But I couldn't find a short-cut since I'm using Mac computer.

Try this:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>

it works.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment on that other question?

Comment: You should post this as an answer so people can vote... I guess... OTOH, it's 100% a perfect answer.

Answer (score 6):

As you said in your question the shortcut on MacOS is:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>

OR

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>

Also you can check all the **shortcuts** in the preferences using <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and go to the `General > Keys` section.

Answer (score 0):

On my MAC I use [OPTION] + [COMMAND] + [DOWN ARROW].

This works with both Eclipse and IntelliJ with the Eclipse keymap setting.